# Error: A JNI error has occurred - SpringBoot - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/modelmapper/ModelMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, modelmapper

I'm trying to run my spring-boot project using the command 'java -jar XXXX.jar' but getting the following error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/modelmapper/ModelMapper   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.modelmapper.ModelMapper   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 7 more

I'm using modelmapper and I declare it as a bean in the following way:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class StartApplication {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In the pom I define the following addiction:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild clean and build?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I always have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, did you get the same message error when it runs?

Comment: Yes, I always have the same error

Comment: Sorry, did you get the same on IDE? looks like your JDK is not answering ...

Comment: I'm working directly from the terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186505/discussion-between-jonathan-johx-and-maurizio-rizzo).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by doing the following steps:

**Step1:** Add [ModelMapper](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper) Library dependency;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Step2:** define the ModelMapper bean in our Spring configuration:

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAppDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SpringBootAppDemo.class);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

**Step3:** Inject and Use ModelMapper

***Entity Class***

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int year;
}
```

***DTO Class***

```
public class StudentDto {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int year;
}
```

***Example***

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

Student student = new Student(...);
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
StudentDto studentDto = modelMapper.map(student, StudentDto.class);
```

**Step4:** Stop your project;

**Step5:** Run the command line `mvn clean`;

**Step6:** Run your project again;

**I hope this will help!!**